# Lineage OS repo size discrepancy

Tags: android, ubuntu, github, size, repo

I am trying to build the Android Lineage OS from the instructions on the official website. I have initialized with 'repo init' and repo sync'd to download the source code successfully.

However the size I found through right-click properties of the source folder doesn't match available free space on the partition. The properties method shows **21.7 GB** and available free space of the partition changed from **92GB to 58.6GB** so the source code should be atleast **33GB** but it is not.

I have let the download run overnight and haven't done anything else while it was doing so. Does the 'repo' tool store temporary files or have a cache of some sort that needs to be cleaned?

I would like to know this so that if I decide to delete the code later on to free up space I want all of it to be gone.

*Note: 'repo sync' did fail once and I had to reissue the command however I believe it should resume and not restart the download.
Note: The same thing happened previously. There was unaccounted used space for another Cynogenmod repo I tried to sync. Similarly it was done overnight and I wasn't using the computer during the download. I think there is something else happening here that I missing.*

Comment: Probably, it is either disk structures or Git metadata

Comment: @JakubKaszycki Thanks. You were right it is hidden metadata in the '.repo' directory that Nautilus wasn't taking into account.

Comment: I can understand your situation, I have faced same situation, I have ssd partition size of 51 GB, thought it will work but it required 3 GB more required to download repo for my Nexus device I have to re-partition  and again have to download all code :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay I guess this more related to Ubuntu than building Lineage OS/repo. I will leave an answer for others that might come looking.

I was able to get total size using `du -sch .[!.]* * | sort -h` in terminal.

Nautilus, the file manager that comes with Ubuntu, doesn't count hidden files/folders by default. And for some reason even when I unhid those folders (Ctrl +H) to get size through right-click properties the count kept restarting every ~30s and never really finished.